# Importing json files into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a couple json files which look like this:

```
data = {"75575": 
            {"name": "Dummy name 1", 
             "season": "", 
             "ep": "", 
             "channel": "Dummy channel 1", 
             "Schedule": ["2017-05-11", "2019-04-30", "", "", "2019-08-01", "2019-08-31", "2017-05-11", "2019-04-30", "", ""]}, 
        "115324": 
            {"name": "Dummy name 2", 
             "season": "", 
             "ep": "", 
             "channel": "Dummy channel 2", 
             "Schedule": ["2017-05-09", "2019-05-31", "2017-05-09", "2019-05-31", "", "", "", "", "2019-09-01", "2019-09-30"]},}
```

I tried to use `json_normalize(data)` but it resulted in `[1 rows x 10 columns]`, so I am using the below workaround:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

for k, v in data.items():
    x = pd.Series(["Dummy genre",k, v.get("name"), v.get("season"), v.get("ep"),
                   v.get("channel"), *v.get("Schedule")],
                  index=("Genre", "ID", "Name", "Season", "Episode", "Channel",
                         "Start date 1", "End date 1", "Start date 2", "End date 2", "Start date 3", "End date 3",
                         "Start date 4", "End date 4", "Start date 5", "End date 5"))
    df = pd.concat([df, x.to_frame().T], ignore_index=True)
```

Is there a way to do it by `json_normalize`? I tried playing around with the [parameters](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) but couldn't wrap my head around it. Also note that I have to ingest 5 different json files with the same format.

My expected output:

```
         Genre      ID     ...     Start date 5  End date 5
0  Dummy genre   75575     ...                             
1  Dummy genre  115324     ...       2019-09-01  2019-09-30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about `json_normalize`, but seems like you can just use regular `pd.DataFrame` constructor

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.Schedule.tolist(), index=df.index)).drop('Schedule', 1)
```

Then simply rename the columns with the list you already have.